# How to retrieve titleLabel on UIButton's prepareForInterfaceBuilder?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, interface-builder

I subclassed `UIButton` and have this following `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` function:

```
- (void)prepareForInterfaceBuilder {
    NSString *string = [self titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                      initWithString:string
                                      attributes:@{
                                                   NSKernAttributeName : @4,
                                                   NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]
                                                   }];
    [self setAttributedTitle:attrString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

It's crashing when viewing in Interface Builder since the string variable is returning nil even though I have "testing" set as the title in Interface Builder. I have also tried retrieving the text by calling `self.titleLabel.text`, but that's also resulting in `nil`.

How do I properly retrieve the titleLabel's text in this function?
Currently using Xcode 7.1 (7B91b).

Comment: would you please share the crash log?

Comment: I tried to play with `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` and looks like it don't allow to do something with button title. But setting title color\other things works fine

Comment: @jamil65able: how do I get a crash log from interface builder? remember this isn't done at standard runtime. I'm getting an agent crashed message in the issue navigator when viewing my storyboard.

Comment: @VitaliyGozhenko: the odd thing is that you can retrieve the text from a `UILabel`, but not a `UIButton`

Comment: Maybe because `titleLabel` initialized during runtime, not in IB

Answer (score 0):

you can set directly Attibuted string to UIButton's Lable

```
NSString *string = @"Your text here";
NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                  initWithString:string
                                  attributes:@{
                                               NSKernAttributeName : @4,
                                               NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]
                                               }];
[yourCustomButton setAttributedTitle:attrString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: I want to convert the text I set in IB to attributed string with formatting. I want to adjust 50 instances of this subclassed UIButton to apply kerning. It's not feasible to manually set the string as you mentioned in your first line of code..